# Как создать мульти массив из простого?

Tags: php

У меня есть массив:

```
$data = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
```

Как добавить к каждому элементу значения чтобы получить такой?

```
$data = array(
    'tags' => array(
        ['name' => 'name1',
        'status' => 'active'],
        ['name' => 'name2',
        'status' => 'active'],
        ['name' => 'name3',
        'status' => 'active']
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
<?php
$data = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
$NewArr = array(
    "tags"=> array()
);

foreach ($data as $val){
    $tempArr = array('name' => $val,
        'status' => 'active');
    array_push($NewArr['tags'],$tempArr);
}
print_r($NewArr);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! :)

Comment: @akasergej Да не за что ) Обращайтесь, если что.

Comment: `array_map` было бы более уместно. тут название функции по крайней мере сразу говорит, что вы как то преобразуете сам массив. а не еще какую то логику делаете

Answer (score 3):

Или короче

```
$data = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
$res = [
    "tags"=> []
];

foreach ($data as $val) {
  $res["tags"][] = [
    'name' => $val,
    'status' => 'active'
  ];
}
```

Или с использованием `array_map()` и анонимной функции

```
$data = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
$res = [
    "tags"=> []
];

$res = array_map(function($val) {
  return [
    'name' => $val,
    'status' => 'active'
  ];
}, $data);
```